# Getting the TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self,first,last,id):
    self._first_name = first
    self._last_name = last
    self._id_number = id
    self._enrolled_in = []

  def enroll_in_course(self,course):
    self._enrolled_in.append(course)
    return self._enrolled_in()

s1 = Student("kathy","lor","323232")

s1.enroll_in_course("hello")

print(s1._enrolled_in)
```

In the code above, i am getting the error as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 14, in
> s1.enroll_in_course("hello")   File "main.py", line 10, in enroll_in_course
> return self._enrolled_in()
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I am trying to solve the error, but unable to do so. Can anybody help me here.

Comment: I think you meant to use `_enrolled_in` on line 9

Comment: i have corrected that minor mistake. @Adithya

Comment: you have to ask new question now for another error.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `self._enrolled_in` but you're adding it to `self.enrolled_in`

Missed the underscore (`self._enrolled_in.append`)

Answer (score 0):

You have called the attribute `_enrolled_in` in your `__init__()` method. In the `enroll_in_course()` method you're trying to append to `enrolled_in` which does not exist. So try by adding the underscore in front.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `_` in the appended statement. You should write `self._enrolled_in.append(course)` on your `enroll_in_course` method.